# How to get the second element from the sublist using python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium

I have automated the script using python selenium to get the data from the site and generated as a list.  Now from the output of sublist i need to get only the second element.
Please do refer the code below which has generated list

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from datetime import datetime
import dateutil.parser
import urllib2
import requests
import htmllib
import sys
import re
import csv
import pandas as pd
from operator import itemgetter
from selenium import webdriver
chrome_path = r"/usr/bin/chromedriver"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_path)
driver.get("http://windspeed.atcouncil.org/")  # opening the site
driver.find_element_by_xpath(
    """//*[@id="address"]""").click()  # click the radio button
driver.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id="google-map-address"]""").click()  # clicking the textbox
cities = ['pheonix']  # city list
for city in cities:
    # print (city)
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id="google-map-address"]""").send_keys(city)  # passing cities
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id="searchform"]/div[1]/div[2]/button""").click()
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("""// *[ @ id = "latt"]""")
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="searchform"]/div[1]/div[7]/span/input').click()
x = driver.current_url
#print x
data = []
newList = []
latest = []
driver.get(x)
s = driver.find_element_by_id('bodyContent')  #search results div
data = '\n'.join(s.text.split('\n')[3:22])
data = str(data).split("\n")
#for each in data:
    #data = data[each].split(':',1)[1]
#print data
#data= [i.split('\t', 1)[0] for i in data]
for i in data:
    newList.append(i.split(':'))
print data
print newList


#[latest.append(x[1]) for x in newList]
#b = map(itemgetter(1), newList)
#print b
if type(newList) is list:
    print 'list'
else:
    print 'none'
```

The output which i got is

```
['Query Date: Wed Aug 16 2017', 'Latitude: 33.4484', 'Longitude: -112.0740', '', 'ASCE 7-10 Windspeeds', '(3-sec peak gust in mph*):', '', 'Risk Category I: 105', 'Risk Category II: 115', 'Risk Category III-IV: 120', 'MRI** 10-Year: 76', 'MRI** 25-Year: 84', 'MRI** 50-Year: 90', 'MRI** 100-Year: 96', '', 'ASCE 7-05 Windspeed:', '  90 (3-sec peak gust in mph)', 'ASCE 7-93 Windspeed:', '  72 (fastest mile in mph)']
[['Query Date', ' Wed Aug 16 2017'], ['Latitude', ' 33.4484'], ['Longitude', ' -112.0740'], [''], ['ASCE 7-10 Windspeeds'], ['(3-sec peak gust in mph*)', ''], [''], ['Risk Category I', ' 105'], ['Risk Category II', ' 115'], ['Risk Category III-IV', ' 120'], ['MRI** 10-Year', ' 76'], ['MRI** 25-Year', ' 84'], ['MRI** 50-Year', ' 90'], ['MRI** 100-Year', ' 96'], [''], ['ASCE 7-05 Windspeed', ''], ['  90 (3-sec peak gust in mph)'], ['ASCE 7-93 Windspeed', ''], ['  72 (fastest mile in mph)']]
list
```

From the above output i want to get the second element which should be like as follows,

```
['Wed Aug 16 2017', '33.4484', '-112.0740', '105', ' 115', ' 120',' 76', ' 84', ' 90',' 96'   '90 (3-sec peak gust in mph)',  '72 (fastest mile in mph)']
```

Comment: Do `newList.append(i.split(':')[1])` instead to just append the second element after splitting.

Comment: when i try using newList.append(i.split(':')[1]) i am getting 
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: Then there are elements which do not have a colon in there which is why nothing is split. You could try `i.split(':')[-1]` then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The information that you are looking for is not under any tag. It is just a part of the `bodyContent` tag. But each separation creates a text Node in HTML. So one can the text Nodes using `/text()` XPATH on the node.

```html
<div id="bodyContent"><h1><b>Search Results</b></h1><br><br><b>Query Date: </b> Wed Aug 16 2017<br><b>Latitude: </b> 33.4484<br><b>Longitude: </b> -112.0740<br><br><b>ASCE 7-10 Windspeeds <br>(3-sec peak gust in mph*):</b><br><br><b>Risk Category I:</b> 105<br><b>Risk Category II:</b> 115<br><b>Risk Category III-IV:</b> 120<br><b>MRI** 10-Year:</b> 76<br><b>MRI** 25-Year:</b> 84<br><b>MRI** 50-Year:</b> 90<br><b>MRI** 100-Year:</b> 96<br><br><b>ASCE 7-05 Windspeed:</b><br> &nbsp; 90 (3-sec peak gust in mph)<br><b>ASCE 7-93 Windspeed:</b><br> &nbsp; 72 (fastest mile in mph)<br><br><p></p><br><p>*Miles per hour<br>**Mean Recurrence Interval</p><br><p>Users should consult with local building officials <br> to determine if there are community-specific wind speed <br> requirements that govern.</p><br><form id="createPDF" action="/pdf/create.php" method="post"><input type="hidden" name="cont" value="<h1><b>Search Results</b></h1><br/><br/><b>Query Date: </b> Wed Aug 16 2017<br/><b>Latitude: </b> 33.4484<br/><b>Longitude: </b> -112.0740<br/><br/><b>ASCE 7-10 Windspeeds <br/>(3-sec peak gust in mph*):</b><br/><br/><b>Risk Category I:</b> 105<br/><b>Risk Category II:</b> 115<br/><b>Risk Category III-IV:</b> 120<br/><b>MRI** 10-Year:</b> 76<br/><b>MRI** 25-Year:</b> 84<br/><b>MRI** 50-Year:</b> 90<br/><b>MRI** 100-Year:</b> 96<br/><br/><b>ASCE 7-05 Windspeed:</b><br/> &nbsp; 90 (3-sec peak gust in mph)<br/><b>ASCE 7-93 Windspeed:</b><br/> &nbsp; 72 (fastest mile in mph)<br/><br/><p></p><br/><p>*Miles per hour<br/>**Mean Recurrence Interval</p><br/><p>Users should consult with local building officials <br/> to determine if there are community-specific wind speed <br/> requirements that govern.</p><br/>"><input type="hidden" name="lat" value="33.4484"><input type="hidden" name="lan" value="-112.0740"><input type="hidden" name="zoom" id="google-map-zoom" value="4"><input type="hidden" name="maptype" id="google-map-maptype" value="roadmap"><!-- <a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('createPDF').submit(); return false;"><img src="/images/pdf.png" border=0 /> Download a PDF of your results</a> --></form><br><a href="#" onclick="window.print(); return false;"><img src="/images/print.png" border="0"> Print your results</a><br><br></div>
```

Now most scraping frameworks or html parse would allow you to extract node data but Selenium is always interested in elements. So it cannot extract things on its own. You need to write some javascript for the same. One can use the `document.evaluate` method to run a XPath and get all its results. The javascript for the same would be as below

```
script_extract_data="""
var data = document.evaluate("./text()", 
             document.getElementById("bodyContent"), null, 
             XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE, null);

var text = [];

for (var i=0; i < data.snapshotLength; i++) 
{
   text.push(data.snapshotItem(i).textContent.trim());
}

return text;
"""
```

And you can execute the script using

```
data = driver.execute_script(script_extract_data)
print(data)
```

The will produce the below output

```
In[4]: driver.execute_script(script_extract_data)
Out[4]: 
['Wed Aug 16 2017',
 '33.4484',
 '-112.0740',
 '105',
 '115',
 '120',
 '76',
 '84',
 '90',
 '96',
 '90 (3-sec peak gust in mph)',
 '72 (fastest mile in mph)']
```

Comment: … JavaScript? This is a Python question.

Comment: Yes, but I still don’t understand why you would write JavaScript here. OP already has the results almost ready.

Comment: Reason being that this would make sure we only read values and not their labels in order. There are multiple ways to solve a problem. I am just proposing one, it is not the only possible solution, but one with less hassles to what is needed