# How to get text next to tag with xpath

Tags: java, selenium, xpath

I Have the following HTML code

```html
<HTML>
<HEAD><TITLE>CTS_Status_20170908_085307</TITLE></HEAD>
<BODY>
<font face=arial>
<b>CTS Status Report</b>
<br><br>
<table border=0>
<tr>
<tr><td>Start time:</td><td>2017-09-06 18:31:28</td></tr>
<tr><td>Current time:</td><td>2017-09-08 08:53:07</td></tr>
</table>
<br>
Last DB maintenance record: N/A<br><br>
Up time: 1 days, 14 hours, 21 minutes, 38 seconds<br><br>
Transactions served: 2718<br><br>
Sessions created from start: 29<br>
Current sessions count: -16<br><br>
DB timeouts count: 3<br>
DB disconnections count: 51<br><br>
Transaction info: <br>
```

And i'm trying to get the information for

```
Up time: 1 days, 14 hours, 21 minutes, 38 seconds
```

I'm doing it with the following xpath

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/font/text()[2]")).getText());
```

but i get the following error

> The result of the xpath expression "/html/body/font/text()[2]" is:
>   [object Text]. It should be an element.

Can anyone help me on this, please.

Comment: which element u want to select

Comment: i'm trying to get the following information
"Up time: 1 days, 14 hours, 21 minutes, 38 seconds"

Comment: FYI: this xPath works in chrome devtools to find your text: `//font[@face]/text()[contains(.,'Up time')]`

Comment: first of all, thanks for your reply..
when i put your code i get the following error
is: [object Text]. It should be an element.

Answer (score 0):

You can only get elements using selenium not text nodes

You should do this

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/font")).getText());
```

And then use regular expression to extract the data you need. Or you can use a JavaScript based approach that I did in below

[How to get the second element from the sublist using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45707185/how-to-get-the-second-element-from-the-sublist-using-python/45716982#45716982)